# Mock not initiated on Static method

Tags: junit, mockito, static-methods

I am facing issues in mocking static method.
Below is my code where I am calling a static method

```java
public class GetAllBatches {
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(route = "v1/batches",
                    name = "request",
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                    HttpRequestMessage<String> request,
            final ExecutionContext context){
        context.getLogger().info("List batches Called");
        String apiResponse ;
        String connector = request.getQueryParameters().getOrDefault("connector", "");
        try{
            BatchesController batchesController = BatchesController.getInstance();
            apiResponse = new Gson().toJson(batchesController.getBatches(connector));
        }
    }
}
```

BatchesController Class :

```java
public class BatchesController {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BatchesController.class.getName());

    public static BatchesController getInstance() {
        if (batchesController == null) {
            batchesController = new BatchesController(BatchDaoFactory.getDao());
        }
        return batchesController;
    }

    private static BatchesController batchesController = new BatchesController();
    private final BatchDao batchDao;

    public BatchesController(BatchDao BatchDao) {
        this.batchDao = BatchDao;
    }
// Do something
}
```

And below is the test that I have :

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetAllBatchesTest {
    @Mock
    ExecutionContext context;
    @Mock
    HttpRequestMessage<String> request;
    @Mock
    BatchesController batchesController;
    @Mock
    BatchDao BatchDao;

    @InjectMocks
    GetAllBatches getAllBatchesMock = new GetAllBatches();

    @Before
    public void setUp()  {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("connector", "");

        doReturn(Logger.getGlobal()).when(context).getLogger();
        doReturn(map).when(request).getQueryParameters();
        try (MockedStatic<BatchesController> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(BatchesController.class)) {
            utilities.when(BatchesController::getInstance).thenReturn(batchesController);
        }
        doAnswer((Answer<HttpResponseMessage.Builder>) invocationOnMock -> {
            HttpStatus status = (HttpStatus) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
            return new HttpResponseMessageMock.HttpResponseMessageBuilderMock().status(status);
        }).when(request).createResponseBuilder(any(HttpStatus.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testHttpTriggerJava()  {

        final HttpResponseMessage ret = getAllBatchesMock.run(request, context);
        Assertions.assertEquals(ret.getStatus(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I run my test, it throws an error message :
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

BatchesController.getInstance() is not actually returning the mock value.

I am not sure what is going wrong here ?

UPDATE :
I found out that the problem is because I am using Mockito-inline Mockito-inline fails to initiate mock on class but initiates mock only on interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You are using a try-with-resources block to setup a static mock:

```java
try (MockedStatic<BatchesController> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(BatchesController.class)) {
    utilities.when(BatchesController::getInstance).thenReturn(batchesController);
}
```

Remember that the static mock is only active in scope of the block - after you exit the block the resource is closed.

Thus, you need to:

- move the static mock initialization from setup method to the test method
- run code under test within the try-with-resources block

Comment: I found out that the problem is because I am using Mockito-inline
Mockito-inline fails to initiate mock on class but initiates mock only on interfaces